# Regular Expression to Match Sequence of Characters

Tags: java, regex

I need a Regular Expression to match a sequence of characters that make up a query.  An example of my definition of a query is like this : **and(cat,dog)** In a more general definition, it can be represented as ***operator(operand, operand)***  It is made up of an operator that contains 2 operands. The operands can be any single ALPHABETIC word(non-numeric) or even another subquery.  and an example is **and(goat,or(zebra,bear))** The operators are **AND, OR, NOT** and a query can get more and more **AMBIGUOUS** to an extent as far as possible. There is no **WHITESPACE** within the query and I need the regex to use in a Java application. Note: A **NOT** operator can have only one operand e.g. **not(tiger)**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. I've fixed your title.

Comment: Better to trying to parse complex expressions like queries using patterns is using lexical and syntax analyzers, like lexx and yacc (bison) in the C world. This give you more powerful to define the tokens you can use and the construction rules (production rules in the grammar). This is far complex to use, but incredible powerful if you can use it. Google for Java with lexx and yacc for Java alternatives to these classics.

Answer (score 2):

The subquery as an operand makes this impossible.  Regular expressions aren't powerful enough for nested stuff, you'll need to use context-free grammars.

Answer (score 0):

Your problematic may be much more complicated and it is hard to guess your exact direction. However, this simple Java example maybe a good start point for you:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "add(1,sub(2,3))";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\((.*)\\)");
    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s);
    if (m1.matches()) {
      System.out.println(m1.group(1));
      System.out.println(m1.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println();
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(m1.group(2));
    if (m2.matches()) {
      System.out.println(m2.group(1));
      System.out.println(m2.group(2));
    }
  }
}
```

Produces output like:

```
add
1,sub(2,3)

1,sub
2,3
```